# How do I Count Cells in Columns of a non-rectangular range

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a range that will be selected by a user. It will be two columns, usually not next to each other. I need to count the number of cells in each column of the selected range to determine if the number of cells in each column is equal. (If it's not I will need to adjust the range.)

For example, a User may select B5:B10 and D6:D9. So I need the code to return 6 and 4 respectively.

I've tried:

```
Set rng = Selection
rng.Columns(1).Count
```

this returns 1, which obviously isn't the number I need.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you also need to check they only selected two columns in total, or does it simply need to be the same number of cells in each area? i.e. if they select A1:C2 and D1:E3 that's the same number of cells but not the same shape.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Areas` method of the `Range` object to get the areas of the range. Areas are groups of contiguous ranges within a non-contiguous range.

```
Set rng = Selection
For i = 1 to rng.Areas.Count
    debug.print rng.Areas(i).Cells.Count
Next
```

There is caveat here that you may need to test for, and that is if the user selects, for example, A1:B10, with one mouse drag. Since this is a contiguous range, it will only have one `Area` and you will not get two distinct numbers. If you need to test for this, you can do something like the below.

```
Set rng = Selection

'non-contiguous ranges will always return one column, if there are mutiple columns both cell counts are equal by default
If rng.Columns.Count = 1 Then
    For i = 1 to rng.Areas.Count
        debug.print rng.Areas(i).Cells.Count
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Dammit @Scott - just beat me to it.

Although I'm using the `Rows` property - if the user selects `A1:B19` it will return 19 in a single element of the array, if they select `A1:A19` and then `B1:B19` it will return 19 in two elements of the array.
Using `Cells` it will return 38 in a single element, or 19 in two elements.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rRange As Range
    Dim lRows() As Long
    Dim x As Long

    Set rRange = Selection

    With rRange
        ReDim lRows(1 To .Areas.Count)
        For x = 1 To .Areas.Count
            lRows(x) = .Areas(x).Rows.Count
        Next x
    End With

End Sub
```